# NSTimer iPhone Question

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, nstimer

I have seen a similar answer for my question but I would just make it clear. My Application needs sends an event to be fired even when the application is not active. I think it cant be done using a NSTimer. My question is that do I need to run the timer in some other runloop other than the main run loop to deliver the runloop, so that it will get delivered even when the application is inactive.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean when the application is closed, you can't.  iPhone applications terminate and there are no background threads left open when the user returns to the main page.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer. So, Is there any other way to do it.Can I do it through the NSNotifications?

Comment: I'm fairly positive that there is no way to wake up an application on the phone without using Push Notifications which require a Push Provider (there are more details on this in the Apple Push Notification Guide) but it's a really heavy solution for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Beside, Push notifications don't actually wake up the application.  They just put a badge on the icon and notify the user that the application has notifications pending.  The app won't actually get a chance to do anything until the user activates it.

joe